# pythonでinstall library をしたときのエラー

Tags: python, unicode, pip

こんにちは。python初心者のものです。私が今使っている教材で
・pip install [library名]
とすると、パッケージをインストールできるとのことですが、画像のようなエラーが出てきました。ググりにググった結果、埒が明かないので質問させていただきました。[image: 実行した結果]

見にくいですが、UnicodeDecodeErrorと出ています。
どなたか解決に力を貸してくれたらうれしいです！

環境：Python 3.6.0, Windows 10

[image: 環境変数に追加して実行]

Comment: pythonのバージョンなど環境を記載頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: 「新」という文字が CP932 encoding では `0x90 0x56` となっていて、標準出力の文字コード(`sys.stdout.encoding`) が `UTF-8` に設定されている事が原因ではないでしょうか。環境変数 `PYTHONIOENCODING` を `cp932` に設定して pip コマンドを実行すれば上手く行くかもしれません。

Comment: Python3.6.0でwindows10を使用しています。

Comment: 環境変数を見てみても、PYTHONIOENCODINGというものが見当たりません。どこにあるのでしょうか？

Comment: どこかにあるのではなくて、新たに追加する、という意味です。

Comment: なるほど、トライしてみます.。

Comment: PYTHONIOENCODING=cp932 と新たに追加してみましたが、どうやら設定は変わってないようです。追加の仕方が間違ってますか？

Comment: それでは `cmd.exe` 上で `set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp932` としてから pip を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: 実行した結果、まだうまくいかないようです。実行した結果の画像を追加しました。環境変数の追加の仕方はあってますか？　初心者ですみません。

Comment: もしかして環境変数 `PATH` の設定部分に追加していないでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば、[Windows10の環境変数(システム環境変数、ユーザ環境変数)を追加](http://www.wannko.net/windows10/etc/kankyo.html)を参照して下さい。「5、値を追加し、OKを選択。」の項で「変数名」に `PYTHONIOENCODING`、「変数値」に `cp932` と入力します。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、PTAHの部分設定に追加していました。次にシステム環境変数、ユーザー変数のどちらにも変数:PYTHONIOENCODING、変数値:cp932を追加して、pipを実行したところ画像のようにまだエラーがでました。

Comment: 確認ですが、`cmd.exe` は再起動しましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます、再起動してもう一度実行した結果うまくいきました(ToT)。本当に感謝です、ありがとうございます！

Comment: @metropolis 一連の結果を回答にまとめていただけませんでしょうか？　ご面倒でしたらコミュニティからの投稿として私がまとめます。